# Social Etiquette for a Winged Sapient

Tags: society, humanoid, sapience

On Damarian, my gas giant moon, many species live and interact, and have their own nation (Often an offspring nation of a nation on the species' home world, as Damarian is a sanctuary planet). One such species is the Pterian, a winged, tailed humanoid (Called Nakayoid by Damarians) native to Aerovia, a mountainous country that is Damarian's resident clone clone.

Enlightened by Tumblr posts about winged humanoid anatomy, here are some basics about Pterian anatomy:

1. Pterians evolved from a heron like species on a mountain planet, and are sensitive to synthetic perfumes and cosmetics.
2. Wings are positioned below the arms (Just below), and look like white heron wings with black primary and secondary wings. They also have small rudder wings on their calves for maneuvering.
3. The wings are waterproofed by the wing feather tips disintegrating as they grow. Preening is a social activity that makes them healthy and bonded with friends and family.
4. They are obligate carnivores that can't really eat vegetables or nuts.
5. They lay eggs and feed hatchlings with crop food from either parent.
6. They are monogamous and egalitarian, as anyone, male or female, can feed a hatchling and look after it.

How would wings affect a species' etiquette?

Comment: Given how many different sets of rules of etiquette there are for our species, what makes you think there is a definitive answer more specific than "They would definitely have rules surrounding their wings". This seems like a question where every answer is equally correct. Such opinion based questions are a poor fit for this site.

Comment: I feel like this is a whole "_please create a culture for me_" type question, which is far to complex to squeeze into a reasonably sized answer, amongst other problems. Perhaps ask something a bit more specific?

Comment: @sphennings While rules of etiquette may seem arbitrary, it is rarely the case. Most rules have some justification behind them. A lot of our rules are directly associated with human biology and mating practices. The question is still too broad, but it does not mean that it is opinion-based, or that there is no way to answer it without relying on speculation only, or that all answers are equally correct. For one, given the description, it is almost 100% certainty that Pterians will have rules preventing the overuse of perfumes.

Comment: Too open, too opinion, and far too "please create my society"...... as per other comments to.the OP.

Comment: I'd really love to vote to reopen this, as it is a wonderful *basis* for a series of good cultural questions. However, it is way too broad. I'd suggest that you edit this question and focus on some narrower aspect of social etiquette: casual social situations, religious rites, interactions with non Nakayoids. You should be able to get half a dozen good questions out of this!

Comment: @Otkin if u wiĺling to provide answer to it then I will  ote for open. A good answer about eticete in general and what's applicable to this specific case may be helfull, maybe

Comment: @MolbOrg As I said, this is too broad. The OP also does not provide enough details to talk about specific rules, especially those associated with having wings.

Comment: @Otkin oh, yeah, that glorious 3in1 - broad-opinion-need details. Borders between those are very vague in this one, and force is stronk, lol. Basically, the q has no relevant details, besides that one bit of like\dislike. A practical approach is to opinion-based define a set of likes dislikes and try to work from the situation - optimistic take, but maybe. The answer here could be provided In a sense what needs to be defined, what are influential factors on forming such things - so theory and references to materials with those theories. Not sure someone is capable enough or else I would vto it

Comment: @MolbOrg I disagree. This question is not opinion-based unless we assume that etiquette is completely arbitrary and has no logic behind it whatsoever. It is not answerable in its current form, but mainly because we do not know about the social and cultural norms that this society has. If we knew more about species biology we would be able to derive some of the most likely to develop cultural norms, but we do not have this information.

Comment: @Otkin it is more semantics, but it's opinion-based because of arbitrarity of input data and OP has no way to provide sufficient enough data. Closure reason isn't a verdict on etiquette relationships with reality to be arbitrary matter, the answer to the q is arbitrary matter, not the subject of the q. So it's exactly how you say it, so again, why do we discuss it, lol?

Comment: @MolbOrg It is the OP's world. They **can** supply all the necessary details.

Comment: @Otkin User can't. The User is just a mere human. The user owns no world. At best is a subjective illusion of having sufficient idea to start to imagine things. So it is not just a matter of describing what's already there, observing, but even if it was(it is not, but if) even then the user can't and it can be seen on any historical records made by people who spend lives on describing(often incorrectly) things about other nations and other people in the past. Or present - understanding different nations is such mind draining task, so complex - information is all around but it does not helps.

Comment: User's physical inability to provide sufficient information and our incapacity to process it in any meaningful way  - on one side and practical problem of constructing some system of social relationships which may look like some sort of match to users description and clear ability of some people to do so - is the only argument for opening this and similar questions. Inability to provide sufficient data, ability to provide passable solutions in practices - makes such formulations and q's somewhat acceptable in some cases, not sure about this one - not my specialty.

Answer (score 2):

Etiquette is a complex thing, and situation dependent. I'd have to compile a list of all plausible social interactions, which isn't something I plan on doing.

However. A few things you might want to bear in mind. (would have commented it, but I don't meet the reputation requirement)

Wings are limbs. That means, they need to move sometimes or they'll get that pins and needles feeling and make the person miserable. Are there situations when suddenly moving your wings is a faux pas?

It's hard to mind what's going on behind you. And with wings that sometimes just need/want to move, it becomes easy to knock into things you can't see. Does that lead to different interior designs? Vases just on a pedestal seems a recipe for disaster. And offering fellow winged creatures more personal space to not get a wing jabbed in your face could prove beneficial.

Do people dye their feathers? Is that common? A sign of rebellion? Is it like face piercings to humans?

Molting season could be a thing. Molting sometimes has birds irritable. What customs would need to be in place to help alleviate this?

Is there a mating season? Do they ovulate/mate throughout the year? There are more etiquette rules around courting and mating behaviour than almost any other in most human societies.

Social animals (including humans) have/make up rules around almost everything we do. From eating, to hunting, to mating, to courting, to dressing, to decorating. For this we've had a slew of sumptuary laws throughout the ages to ensure people 'stay in their lane'--is that a thing?

This is why the comments are saying there's no one way to answer, or even a way to gauge which answer would fit best. Too many variables.